# Lay out objects programmatically in a diamond shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, sprite-kit

I know this isn't strictly a Objective-C matter but its what I know and I figured I might as well make use of some of the amazing talent on this site for this problem.

I am trying to lay objects out in a diamond format (see image) for a Sprite Kit game. I am battling to figure out a way to do this.

The centre block (13) will be aligned to the centre of the screen `(self.size.width/2), (self.size.height/2)`

[image: Object Layout]

I am using the following definitions as a basis of my layout

```
#define kLevel_01_GridSize 5
#define kLevel_01_SpacingX 75
#define kLevel_01_SpacingY 32
```

The follow code is all I have at this point. It places the very first block (1)

```
-(void)layoutLevel {

    int gridCentre = (kLevel_01_GridSize - 1) / 2;
    int totalObjects = kLevel_01_GridSize * kLevel_01_GridSize;


    CGPoint objectPosition;

    for (int x = 1; x < totalObjects; x++)
    {

        objectPosition = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2 , (self.size.height /2 ) + (x * gridCentre) * kLevel_01_SpacingY);

        SKNode *block = [self makeBlockOfType:LevelBlock];
        block.position = objectPosition;
        [self addChild:block];
    }
}
```

Please also bare in mind that I would like the objects to be placed in order of the numbers in the picture. This will assist in maintaining their layer order.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic trig and geometry problem - the nuts and bolts of computer graphics

You could either use trig to figure out the step value for each x and y (it would be sqrt(2)/2 * square_side_length) and then write code loops through x and y, offsetting the position by that amount,

or you could calculate your positions based on a non-rotated square shape, and then apply a 45 degree (pi/2) transformation matrix to the coordinates before plotting them.

Calculating where to place the numbers would take a little thought.

When you say "I might as well make use of some of the amazing talent on this site for this problem." it sounds a lot like "I figured I might try to get somebody else to do my work for me for free."

Nope.

I'm happy to write this code for you - for my usual consulting fee. Otherwise I'll offer suggestions and help, but I'm not gonna do you work for you.

Thinking about how to handle the numbers, here is what I came up with. Rotate your rectangle 45 degrees counterclockwise so the 1 is in the upper-left corner. Then label the x and y coordinates of each cell starting at 0. So the cell with 1 in it is at 0,0. The cell with 3 in it is at 1,0.

You can create a lookup table that gives you the x/y coordinates of any given cell. Something like this

```
define cellWidth  50.0
#define gridSize 5

  typedef struct
  {
    int x;
    int y;
  } gridPosition;

  //For all the cells, here are the values at each x/y position
/*
    x   0  1  2  3  4
    |  -- -- -- -- --
y   |
0   |  01 03 06 10 15
1   |  02 05 09 14 19
2   |  04 08 13 18 22
3   |  07 12 17 21 24
4   |  11 16 20 23 25
 */

  //Then  create an array of 25 gridPosition objects and populate each one with the grid coordinates of that
  //value

  gridPosition positions[25] = {
    {.x= 0, .y= 0},  //Value 1 at (0,0)
    {.x= 0, .y= 1},  //Value 2 at (0,1)
    {.x= 1, .y= 0},  //Value 3 at (1,0)
    {.x= 0, .y= 2},  //Value 4 at (0,2)
    //and so on for all 25 entries..
  };


  CGPoint cellCenter;
  int x, y;
  int cellIndex;
  gridPosition cellPosition;
  for (y = 0; y < gridSize; y++)
    for (x = 0; x < gridSize; x++)
    {
      cellIndex = y*gridSize + x;
      cellPosition = positions[cellIndex];
      cellCenter = CGPointMake(
                               cellWidth/2.0 + cellPosition.x*cellWidth,
                               cellWidth/2.0 + cellPosition.y*cellWidth);
    }
```

Comment: Firstly I appreciate your help and respect you as someone who contributes to this site and others. I do however think that you misunderstand my intentions. My basic trig and geometry is non-existent, yet I have been struggling on this for about a week before making this post. While your first method is over my head I have considered the second but as you say placing the numbers is an issue. I'll sit down and think about it some more.

Comment: If you're not comfortable using trig then using a transformation matrix might be the way to go. GLKit has support for 2D and 3D transformation matrix math. You could lay out your rectangle non-rotated, then apply a 45 degree rotation to the center and each corner before plotting. You'd use centered layout for the labels and simply move their centers to the rotated center coorindate of each tile.

Comment: Thank you Duncan. I think I have a concept now which may work. Setting the zPosition values after the layout might also simplify things. I'm going to leave the question open for now until I piece it together.

Comment: This is a 2d grid, so z should always be zero. Note that I just posted some code that uses a simple lookup table to map out your cell layout.